# Generate PDF with Telerik Reporting with .NET Core

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core, pdf-generation, telerik-reporting

Currently, we want to implement a PDF generator with telerik reporting.

We would like to create the PDF with our own customized designer template and supply it with a data model.

The following code shows a route that will export a PDF file with the template: "confirmation.trdp" (see attachment).

It's a dummy file that I created for testing purpose.

Here is the source code I have:

```
 public IActionResult Pdf()
 {
        // mock data
        var dataModel = new MockData
        {
            Name = "Terence",
            Amount = 1000
        };
        var dataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource
        {
            DataSource = dataModel
        };


        var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
        var reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.UriReportSource
        {
            Uri = "PDF/confirmation.trdp"
        };
        //reportSource.Parameters


        var result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, null);
        var output = result.DocumentBytes;

        return File(output, "application/pdf");
  }
```

Here is the template I created from Telerik Report Designer
[image: re]

Here is my question:

How can I bind the text boxes with the data model in the pdf file? And how to configure the.trdp template for that?

Comment: The fact that you want to export your report as PDF seems irrelevant for the questions you are asking, I suggest you take that part out of your question to simplify it. Also, focus on one problem at a time, if you try to ask 3 questions in one, your question is likely to get closed..

Comment: @yms sounds good. I'll focus on the most important one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse *.trdp file to Telerik Report object.

```
var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
var deviceInfo = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

var reportPackager = new ReportPackager();
Report report;
InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new InstanceReportSource();
using (var sourceStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
   report = (Report)reportPackager.UnpackageDocument(sourceStream);
}
```

After that you can change report datasource. For example (with JsonDataSource):

```
                var ds = new JsonDataSource
                {
                    DataSelector = "$",
                    Source = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                    })
                };

                report.DataSource = ds;

                instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = report;

                Telerik.Reporting.Processing.RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, deviceInfo);
```

If you are using Telerik Reports in .NET Core don't forget to add all NuGet dependencies.
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/use-reports-in-net-core-apps